# Find intervals ignoring 15 seconds gaps

Tags: r, time-series, intervals

I have data with samples taken every 15 seconds. My example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:16,
  datetime = seq(
    as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:00:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:03:45"),
    "15 sec"
  ) ,
  Value = c(
    1000, 1200, 50, 67, 23, 200, 344, 3444, 10, 1200, 2000, 60, 60, 10, 20, 1000 ))
```

I need to find intervals where value < 100. So I filtered my data:

dat <- dat %>% filter (Value < 100)

The result:

```
  id            datetime Value
1  3 2020-12-26 10:00:30    50
2  4 2020-12-26 10:00:45    67
3  5 2020-12-26 10:01:00    23
4  9 2020-12-26 10:02:00    10
5 12 2020-12-26 10:02:45    60
6 13 2020-12-26 10:03:00    60
7 14 2020-12-26 10:03:15    10
8 15 2020-12-26 10:03:30    20
```

Now I need to find intervals ignoring 15 seconds gaps. Result I need:

```
    start                    end
1. 2020-12-26 10:00:30       2020-12-26 10:01:00
2. 2020-12-26 10:02:00       2020-12-26 10:02:00
3. 2020-12-26 10:02:45       2020-12-26 10:03:30
```

How to reach it?

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:16,
  datetime = seq(
    as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:00:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:03:45"),
    "15 sec"
  ) ,
  Value = c(
    1000, 1200, 50, 67, 23, 200, 344, 3444, 10, 1200, 2000, 60, 60, 10, 20, 1000 ))


dat <- dat[dat$Value<100,]

diffBigger15 <- which(c(TRUE,diff(as.numeric(dat$datetime))>15))

res <- data.frame(
  start = dat$datetime[diffBigger15],
  end = dat$datetime[c(diffBigger15[-1]-1,NROW(dat))]
)
```

resulting in

```
> res
                start                 end
1 2020-12-26 10:00:30 2020-12-26 10:01:00
2 2020-12-26 10:02:00 2020-12-26 10:02:00
3 2020-12-26 10:02:45 2020-12-26 10:03:30
```